# Create folder for user at registration

Tags: codeigniter

I am novice to codeigniter.Please somebody help me to create a folder to store user information at rgistration.Creating folder should happen parallel with registration. It mean both registration and creating folder should happen by single button

## THIS IS MY CONTROLLER

public function index() {

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'trim|required');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Confirmed Password', 'trim|required');



//run validation on post data
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{   //validation fails
    $this->load->view('Registration');
}
else
{

    //insert the contact form data into database
    $data = array(

        'user_name' => $this->input->post('user_name'),
        'confirm_password' => $this->input->post('confirm_password'),



    );
    $data1 = array(


          'username' => $this->input->post('user_name'),

          'password' =>md5 ($this->input->post('confirm_password')),

          );


     $this->db->insert('registration', $data);
    if ($this->db->insert('users', $data1))
    {
        // success
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">We received your message! Will get back to you shortly!!!</div>');
        redirect('Welcome/index');
    }
    else
    {
        // error
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Some Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
        //redirect('login/HomePage');
    }
}
```

}

## THIS IS MY VIEW

```
    <form class="well form-horizontal" action="<?php echo site_url('Registration/index'); ?>"  method="post"  id="contact_form">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Sign Up</legend>
              <br /> <br />
<div class="form-group">


  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="your email address" id="txtuser" class="form-control" >
  <span class="input-group-btn">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"  right id="chk_avail" class="btn btn-danger" role="button" >Check Availability</a>
      </span>

  </div>
     <div id="msgbx_err" class="alert-box error"><span>error: </span>User already exist with same name.</div>
         <div id="msgbx_success" class="alert-box success"><span>success: </span>Username available.</div>



</div>

<!-- Text input-->


<div class="form-group">


    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <input name="user_password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"  type="password" id="pass1">
    </div>

</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">


    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" name="confirm_password" id="pass2" onkeyup="checkPass(); return false;" required/>


    </div>
    <span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>

</div>





<!-- Button -->
 <button id="btn_login" name="btn_login" type="submit"  class="btn btn-success center-block btn-sign-in"  value="Sign In" >  Sign In   </button>  

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mkdir for create folder. Use it just after the insert of user details in your controller.

```
$this->db->insert('registration', $data);
$userName=$this->input->post('user_name'),
mkdir("/".$userName);
```

Comment: Sorry Mr. Yadhu I can't understand that,,I want to know how to send user id from view to controller and then how to create folder for that given userid

Comment: Have you done anything yet. Then paste the code in your question

Comment: I did it Mr.Yadhu'

Comment: are you able to insert user details. do you want the folder name same as user id????

Comment: yes i was. I want to create a folder for username at registration. One submit button should do save details and create folder both

Comment: what folder name do you want. Is it same as userid

Comment: user_name is needed

Comment: THANK YOUUUUUUUUUU VERY MUCH....GREAT HELP.. I was totally confused with this..thanks in advance Mr.Yadhuu